# How to Find the Previous version of Android of an existing App from the Google Play Store or google console?

Tags: android, google-play, android-version

I am trying to find if there is any way to find the the list of version of an existing android app with the date. For example, the development team has published an app in google play store, with 5 major and minor bug fixes with the different version in the last six months but they don't have the date on which they have published. Is there a way to find the report of an app in Google Play Store or Google Play Console?

I have tried searching in google play console, I can find the usage statistics not the publication statistics

The actual result: I would like to know in which date the major and minor fix app published in the play store with the date and the version number.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the method, where you can find the history of all the activities from google play console. Here you go:
Log into google play console > Click on Launch play console > click on your app name > click on the App release from the left side of the menu bar under release management.

Under Production track > click on manage > you can see release history > expand and you can find the release history of your app.